# syntax for deleting null values in sqlyog

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to delete null values from a table of sql. in normal way we have such this syntax:

```
 String query = "delete from users where arg1 = ?";
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setInt(1, 3);
```

What is syntax when our query is like this:

```
DELETE FROM users 
WHERE arg1 IS NULL AND Rel IS NULL AND Arg2 IS NULL;
```

I tried above mentioned syntax with null values but it didn't work.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding variables won't circumvent the fact that you need to use the `is` operator instead of `=` when handling `null`s:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE arg1 IS NULL AND Rel IS NULL AND Arg2 IS NULL";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.executeQuery();
```